# How to do this recursive code without memo, with memoization?

Tags: c++, recursion, memoization

I know what is memoization but having this recursive code:

```
int F(int n , int T ){

    int ganancia ;
    int maximum = INT_MIN;



    if( T >= 0  &&  n == 0){

        maximum = 0;

    }else if( T < 0){

        maximum = INT_MIN;

    } else if(T >= 0  &&  n > 0){

        for(int i = 0 ; i <= m[n-1] ; i++){

            ganancia = i*v[n-1] + F(n- 1,T- i*t[n-1]);

                if(ganancia > maximum){

                    maximum = ganancia;

                }
        }
    }

    return maximum;
}
```

I don't know how to transform into memoization. I have done something like this:

```
int F_alm(int n, int T){

    int ganancia ;
    int maximum = INT_MIN;

    //PETA POR ESTO
    if(almacen_rec[n-1][T] != -1){

        return almacen_rec[n-1][T];

    }else if( T >= 0  &&  n == 0){

        maximum = 0;

    }else if( T < 0){

        maximum = INT_MIN;

    } else if(T >= 0  &&  n > 0){

        for(int i = 0 ; i <= m[n-1] ; i++){

            ganancia = i*v[n-1] + F(n- 1,T- i*t[n-1]);

                if(ganancia > maximum){

                    maximum = ganancia;

                }
        }
    }

    almacen_rec[n-1][T] = maximum;
    return maximum;

}
```

The objective is to have the variable almacen_rec (it is initialized previously all as -1) like this picture:[image: Memo table]

I leave you the general function of the exercise:
[image: General function]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: return almacen_rec[n][T]; looks wrong : n-1 ?

Comment: Oh yes! But still is returning wrong table.
My program returns a memo table without changing anything, all spaces with -1.
Thanks!

Comment: Better said than before, my program return all spaces with -1 except the solution space, that is correct. So my problem is with the subproblems of the memoization, that are not solved.

Comment: welcome to [so]. if you have additional information to clarify your question, please add the information directly to your question. *comments* are not the place for this.

Answer (score 0):

Below I marked the changes needed to implement memoization in your code with `// *`. I'm assuming the code is in C++, so that I can use [std::pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) and [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) from the standard library.

```
std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int> table; // * (A global variable)

int F(int n , int T ){

    // See if we've already computed this value 
    std::pair<int, int> pair(n, T); // *
    if (table.find(pair) != table.end()) { // *
        return table[pair]; // *
    } // *

    int ganancia ;
    int maximum = INT_MIN;



    if( T >= 0  &&  n == 0){

        maximum = 0;

    }else if( T < 0){

        maximum = INT_MIN;

    } else if(T >= 0  &&  n > 0){

        for(int i = 0 ; i <= m[n-1] ; i++){

            ganancia = i*v[n-1] + F(n- 1,T- i*t[n-1]);

                if(ganancia > maximum){

                    maximum = ganancia;

                }
        }
    }
    // Store the value so we won't have to compute it again later if needed
    table[pair] = maximum; // *
    return maximum;
}
```